# How to add bouncy effect in marker added in openlayers

Tags: dictionary, openlayers, marker

Is there any way to add bouncy effect while adding marker on map in open Layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect is not built in to openlayers but you can make it bouncy yourself with some creative javascript by using [OpenLayers.Tween](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Tween-js.html).

Here's an [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/tests/manual/tween.html).